Cordova platform add iOS without internet connection
I'm working on a Cordova iPad app of a company who wants the Cordova environment built on a device without internet connection.
So far, I have managed to install Nodejs and Cordova on it successfully through transferring relevant files.
My question is how to then add an iOS platform on a cordova project on said device.
Things I've tried:

cordova platform add /path/to/cordova-ios : npm install is called internally to install cordova-ios' dependencies and therefore expects an internet connection.
On an online device, npm i cordova-ios then npm-bundle, then on the offline device, cordova platform add /path/to/created/cordova-ios.tar : its dependencies are installed parallel to cordova-ios and not within its node_modules folder, so npm-bundle does not include the dependencies. Upon running cordova platform add, it fails to install the dependencies.

The only other solution I can come up with is to have something like Verdaccio to set up a local npm registry and publish cordova-ios and its dependencies there, but it feels absurd to do that just to add an iOS platform for Cordova.
Any help is appreciated!

"who wants the Cordova environment built on a device without internet connection" can you confirm you are being asked to develop with cordova on a computer that has no access to the internet ?

@Eric Yes that is the case, although specifically I am asked to set up and build the iPad app with cordova on a computer without internet.

life is too short for that kind of stuff.

What I'm getting is that it's a fruitless endeavour...
